# Reading files remotely

Tags: java

Is it possible to read files from remote computers in JAVA and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can read  using FTP, NFS, HTTP, Windows shares and more.  The precise way to do it depends on what protocol you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But only if they are shared by some mechanism like SMB, FTP, NFS, HTTP...

[**WebDAV**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) is way of sharing files over HTTP. And there are JAVA API'S to read from same.

JCIFS is the answer if the folders are exported as Widnows shares (http://jcifs.samba.org/).

Apache Commons VFS is a common API for accessing files through a lot of different protocols (http://commons.apache.org/vfs/).

Answer (score 0):

You mean reading an URL? Then http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/URLReader.htm is your friend